# Spring Batch - Is it possible for Job_Instance to have multiple Job_execution?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm just wondering whether its possible for a single Job_instance in spring Batch to have multiple Job_execution if so can anyone please explain the process? And also for step_execution please !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a job instance can have multiple job executions. The typical use case is when a job instance has a first execution that fails, and a second (or subsequent) execution that succeeds.

This is explained in details with concrete examples in the [Domain language of Batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/domain.html#job) section of the reference documentation.